# Arithmetic operation in json_query (syntax wrong) - Ansible

Tags: ansible, percentage, json-query

I have the following dictionary:

```yaml
   dict1: {x: 1, y: 2}
```

I want to add third value z that should be (x/y)*100, or in other words percentage.

This is the code I wrote, but something is wrong with the syntax for this arithmetic operation.

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  connection: local
  vars:
    dict1: {x: 1, y: 2}
  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        all3: "{{ dict1 | json_query('{x: x, y: y, z: (x|int'/''y|int''*'100) }') }}"

    - debug:
        msg: "{{all3}}"
```

Error message is

> "msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ',', got 'y'. String: {{ dict1 | json_query('{x: x, y: y, z: (x|int'/''y|int''*'100) }') }}"

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `json_query` for this. Meanwhile, if you deadly want to use it, you can but you will have to compute your calculation in the exact same way (i.e. in a jinja2 expression) as (unless I totally missed something) the [jmespath specification](https://jmespath.org/specification.html) does not mention any arithmetic operator. The below example demonstrates 2 methods which will lead to the same result.

The playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dict1:
      x: 1
      y: 2

    my_value: "{{ dict1.x | int / dict1.y | int * 100 }}"

    all3_combine: "{{ dict1 | combine({'z': my_value | float}) }}"

    my_q: >-
      {x: x, y: y, z: `{{ my_value | float }}`}
    all3_jq: "{{ dict1 | json_query(my_q) }}"
    
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: all3_combine

    - debug:
        var: my_q

    - debug:
        var: all3_jq
```

Gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all3_combine": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 50.0
    }
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "my_q": "{x: x, y: y, z: `50.0`}"
}

TASK [debug] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "all3_jq": {
        "x": 1,
        "y": 2,
        "z": 50.0
    }
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

---

Following your comment and about working on a list of this type of data: this is a typical case where it might be easier to write some lines of python if you are willing to.

Create a custom filter in `filter_plugins/my_xy_filters.py` (in the same directory as your playbook)

```py
def add_percent_as_z(orig_dict):
    """Add a third z key containing the percentage calculation"""
    result = []
    for p in orig_dict:
        p['z'] =  p['x'] / p['y'] * 100
        result.append(p)
    return result


class FilterModule(object):
    """my xy filters."""

    def filters(self):
        """Return the filter list."""
        return {
            'add_percent_as_z': add_percent_as_z
        }
```

Now your playbook becomes:

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    dict_list:
      - x: 1
        y: 2
      - x: 23
        y: 12
      - x: 123
        y: 456

  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ dict_list | add_percent_as_z }}"
```

And gives:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "x": 1,
            "y": 2,
            "z": 50.0
        },
        {
            "x": 23,
            "y": 12,
            "z": 191.66666666666669
        },
        {
            "x": 123,
            "y": 456,
            "z": 26.973684210526315
        }
    ]
```

Comment: This works for sure, thanks. However, does anyone knows is this possible to do with json_query (don't ask me why :))?

Comment: Yeah, neither have I seen it. Just wasn't sure even though there are no arithmetic operands in json_query itself, can it use what's already built-in in Ansible (like calling "external" command and operands).

Comment: Let's say we use first solution you provided. How can I do the same if I had a list of dicts 
 
dict2: [{x: 1, y: 2},{x: 3, y: 4},{x: 5, y: 6}] . 

This is how I can do it for the first key-value pairs
my_value2: "{{ dict2[0].x | int / dict2[0].y | int * 100 }}"

But how would it be in a loop for all members?

Comment: probably something like this, but I get a message 'list object' has no attribute 'x'
- set_fact:
      my_value3: "{{ dict2.x | int / dict2.y | int * 100 }}"
   with_items: dict2

Comment: I found the solution
    - set_fact:
         my_value3: "{{ item.x / item.y * 100}}"
      with_items: "{{dict2}}"

Comment: Thanks for additional answer. One more thing, not sure is it ok to put it in here or create a new question, but how do I save the whole output from the loop, if I put register at the end it does not give me all percentage values, but just one

Comment: 1) create a new question for new questions 2) for your next question make sure to include the full context from start so people answering don't have to adapt their asnwer to a moving requirement 3) don't add information needed to answer your question in comments, [edit] your question. You might also want to review [ask] and [mre] to enhance your next posts. Good luck.